# Macros Written in Excel for Windows Not working in Mac Excel

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I use a mac for work and a coworker has sent me an excel workbook with two macros in it, that for some reason, do not work in Excel for Mac. I was hoping someone has run into this and can review the VBA Macros below and tell me how to edit them to get this functioning on the mac. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**1.SQLResults2XL:**

````
Public Sub SQLResults2XL()

    Dim i           As Long
    Dim j           As Long
    Dim ri          As Long  'row in  index
    Dim ro          As Long  'row out index
    Dim colCount    As Long
    Dim rowCount    As Long
    Dim posStart    As Long
    Dim posLen      As Long
    Dim sheetCount  As Long
        
    Dim str         As Variant
    Dim lines()     As String
    Dim line        As String
    Dim row()       As String
    Dim colWidth()  As Integer
    Dim rows()      As String
    Dim ws          As Worksheet
        
    Dim hRE             As RegExp
    Dim hMatches        As MatchCollection
    
    Dim tRE             As RegExp
    Dim tMatches        As MatchCollection
               
    Set hRE = New RegExp
    With hRE
        .MultiLine = False
        .Global = False
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "[^- ]"
    End With
    
    Set tRE = New RegExp
    With tRE
        .MultiLine = False
        .Global = False
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "^[(][0-9]*[ ][r][o][w][(][s][)][ ][a][f][f][e][c][t][e][d][)]"
    End With
    
    'get the clipboard and change it to a string array of rows
    str = Clipboard2Text()
    str = Replace(str, Chr(13), "")
    lines = Split(str, Chr(10))
    rowCount = UBound(lines)
    
    'shut of updates to the screen
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  
    'for each worksheet in the clipboard, a worksheet is defined by a row of dashes (begin) to "(x row(s) affected)"
    For ri = 0 To rowCount
    
        line = Trim(lines(ri))
        Set hMatches = hRE.Execute(line)
        Set tMatches = tRE.Execute(line)
               
        If Len(Trim(line)) = 0 Then
            'skip this line
        ElseIf hMatches.Count = 0 Then
            GoSub newWorksheet
        ElseIf tMatches.Count > 0 Then
            GoSub endOfWorksheet
        Else
            GoSub processDetailLine
        End If
        
    Next ri
    
    'make the changes visable
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    Exit Sub

processDetailLine:
    If colCount = 0 Then Return 'dashed line has not been processed
      
    'get the details
    posStart = 1
    
    'i is column counter
    For i = 0 To colCount
        posLen = colWidth(i)
        rows(ro, i) = Trim(Mid(line, posStart, posLen))
        posStart = posStart + posLen + 1 'skip the space
    Next i
    ro = ro + 1
        
    Return

newWorksheet:
    sheetCount = sheetCount + 1
    If sheetCount > 1 Then
        Set ws = sheets.Add
    Else
        Set ws = ActiveSheet
    End If
    
    'get the dashed lines, this will provide column widths
    row = Split(line, " ")
    colCount = UBound(row)
    
    'setup the arrays
    ReDim colWidth(colCount)
    ReDim rows(rowCount - 1, colCount)
                        
    'get the column widths
    For i = 0 To colCount
        colWidth(i) = Len(Trim(row(i)))
    Next i
    ro = 0
    
    If ri > LBound(lines) Then
        line = Trim(lines(ri - 1))
        GoSub processDetailLine
        End If
           
    Return
    
endOfWorksheet:
    'move the date to excell
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws.Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(rowCount - 1, colCount))
    rng.Clear
    
    rng = rows()
    rng.Columns.AutoFit
    
    Set rng = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, colCount))
    rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    rng.Font.Bold = True

    Return

               
End Sub```

2.Rename Worksheets:

```Sub RenameWorksheets()

    Dim rng     As Range
    Dim address As String
    Dim ws      As Worksheet
    
    address = ActiveCell.address
    Set rng = Range(address, address)
    
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Range(address, address) > "" Then ws.Name = ws.Range(address, address)
    Next ws
    
    
    
End Sub
````

Comment: You would need to totally rewrite the code to work as it is based on regex, which will not work on Mac.

Comment: Thanks Scott! 

Can anyone assist in the rewrite?? I did not write the regex code, nor do I know how to edit this, unfortunately. :(

Comment: That is not what this site is for.  We do not rewrite code.  You, or the person from whom you got the code, will need to try to do it and then come back for specific help with errors in the code, creating a [mcve].

Comment: Do a little research on using Regex in Mac Excel. There are packages available -- I've not used them so cannot vouch for it, but that is where you could start your research.

Comment: Welcome to SO. FYI, Ron De Bruin is the Mac VBA guru: https://www.macexcel.com/. You'll need to do some custom string manipulation to replace Regex. Suggest reading up on VBA strings e.g. https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-string-functions/

Comment: `Clipboard2Text` may also be broken on Mac - no way to know without the code.  FYI that doesn't look like a complex Regex so you should be able to use straight VBA and  (eg) `Like` for that check.

Comment: Thanks Absinthe. I am going to email Ron about this as well, while researching on my own.